# Social Media Follow/Share Button not Load properly in firefox

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, social-media

i m trying below code for displaying my twitter follow button on wordpress site and in firefox browser not displaying that button while in all other browsers its working perfect...

```
 <a href="https://twitter.com/mytwittername" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="true" data-size="small">Follow @mytwitter</a>

    <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}

(document,"script","twitter-wjs");

</script>
```

my site dont have SSL so because of that is that getting problem to load properly in firefox...?? and google+ also not displaying properly...

this problem only in Firefox Browser..

ANY HELP WOULD BE APPRECIATE !!

Comment: SSL is irrelevant here.

Comment: i know what's the issue but not able to solve that...

Comment: <div data-scribe="component:button" class="btn-o" style="width: 0px;"><a id="b" class="btn" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?original_referer=http%3A%2F%2Ftwc5.com%2Fdemo%2Ftim_blog%2F&amp;ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw&amp;text=Socialite.js&amp;tw_p=tweetbutton&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Ftwc5.com%2Fdemo%2Ftim_blog%2Fan-easy-trick-for-dicing-weird-shaped-veggies%2F"><i></i><span id="l" class="label">Tweet</span></a></div>

Comment: inside iframe there is one div coming i.e class name "btn-o" and in that inline width:0px getting that one is problem,,if will change width to 80px than my problem solved but not able to add using css because its inside iframe...

Comment: Why don't you just add an <a href="linking address"> your emicon </a> on your html file instead?

Comment: i need to show counter also.. if will put ifram than getting everything inside that...

Comment: Have you changed 'style='width: 0px' to the size of your social media icon size.  For example, 34px?

Comment: i got code from twitter site https://about.twitter.com/resources/buttons#tweet

Comment: no i m not able to change its width using css... because its inside ifram and we cant add any css may be inside ifram class

Comment: width:0px automatic set to 0 in firefox...

Comment: SSL is required to solve this issue??

Comment: When you created the button, were you logged into your Twitter account?

Comment: No.  SSL is not the issue.

Comment: no directly i got button creation on twitter site without login

Comment: Try that, because Twitter automatically assigns you the link.

Comment: means once sign on in twitter and generate button after that from this url https://about.twitter.com/resources/buttons#tweet?

Comment: Yes.  Sign in to twitter and use same browser to generate button.

Comment: ok. thanks Muge..let me try this now

Answer (score 0):

The easier way for generating your Twitter social media button is to first
'Log In' to your Twitter account.  Then go to the following link to generate your button:  [link] https://about.twitter.com/resources/buttons#tweet.

Otherwise, if you have not logged in, copy the code where you want your social media button to appear and add **your unique Twitter name** inside the code

```
data-via="YourTwitterName"
```

Comment: Thanks Muge... one more issue i m getting.. pls help me on that

Comment: in my blog site in home page displaying all post one by one in row wise ok,, and in that i have added fb,twitter and other social share functionality and in firefox some of twitter button showing and in some of not coming so what's the issue??? means sometimes coming in all post and sometimes not coming properly...

Comment: i m using this type of code <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://www.google.com" data-via="micky_4687">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>

Comment: Post your website link.

Comment: only problem in firefox browser... counter is displaying in firefox but twitter button not displaying that is the issue

Comment: Can you post your website link here?  It is hard to guess without seeing how things are set up.

Comment: can you give me ur skype if ?

Comment: I can see count on both browsers, Chrome and Firefox.  The one that does not display is 'Printerest'.  Even if zero.

Comment: pls check all post of what's rising portion. in that some of twitter icon coming and in some of not coming sometimes..

Comment: thanks..lets i sended you req.. for sec purpose you can remove above comment